# "mysql" コマンドを実行できない

Tags: mysql, windows-10

mysqlをインストールしたんですがコマンドプロンプトで `mysql -u root -p` を試してみてもパスワードを入れる為のpass:が出てきません。`"mysql"は内部コマンド又は外部コマンドとして認識されていません。` と出ます。
また、管理者用のコマンドプロンプトでnet start mysql57と入れると既に始まっていると出ます。
しかし `mysql -u root -p` は使用出来ません。

MySQLのインストーラーで一応設定はしたんですがどうすればいいのでしょうか。
因みにシステム環境変数のPathにはC:¥Program Files¥MySQL¥MySQL Server 5.7¥binと入れました

Comment: コマンドラインクライアントというのを見つけてそこでなら入れました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「mysqlをダウンロードした」もう少し詳しく記述してください。
インストールした環境は？
初期設定はどこまで行ったのですか？ユーザの作成は？
もしかすると、それ以前で止まってるのかもしれませんが……

インストール直後だと仮定して話をすると
環境変数を追加しましょう。
俗に言う"PATHを通す"と言うやつです。
Windowsに入れたのであれば
`mysql`>`bin`>`mysql.exe`のPATHを環境変数`Path`に追加します。

他のPathなどの絡みもあって環境変数が反映されない。
または環境変数を追加するのが難しい場合
カレントディレクトリを`mysql`>`bin`でコマンドラインを実行して`mysql`でも実行できます。
Macであれば`bash_profile`に実行PATHを追加ですね

それでログインなのですが
初期設定では"root"にパスワードは設定されていなかったはずなので
`mysql -u root`で入れると思います。

また、入ることが出来た場合、
次に"root"にはパスワードを設けましょう。
その後、ユーザの作成　＞　データベースの作成ですかね？

Comment: mysql.exeの代わりにC:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\binをローカル環境変数のPathに追加したところ、mysql -u rootで1045エラーが出るようになりました。その為、mysql -u root -pで試して見たところ正しいはずのパスワードを入れても駄目だったので駄目元で「mysql -u root -ppassword」（mysql -u root -pの語尾にパスワードを入れるという事）で試してみたら何故か入れました。他の方への情報共有の為のコメントです。

Answer (score 0):

mysqlへの接続にこちらを参考にさせていただきました。ありがとうございます。
上記環境変数にてPathを通すところについて、編集するのは「システム環境変数」の方なんですね。
当たり前のことなのでしょうが、素人のため少し躓きましたので補記いたします。